# Django: How to generate unique order id

Tags: django, model, uuid

This is how my model looks like. When ever user orders. The order id provided by django is simple. Its like 1,2,3 ..... 100.

```
class UserOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='orders', 
           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, related_name="orders", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
           blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    total_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    note = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    cancel_reason = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    cancelled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not well defined but I think I understand your problem, you need a id (lookup field) that is not simple.

you can use uuid, and use this uuid for all the lookup in the viewsets, instead of the sequentially created id by django.
something like this lookup_field = 'uuid' in views.

```
import uuid

class UserOrder(models.Model):
     uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, db_index=True, editable=False)
```

read more about uuids here https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4

Answer (score 0):

try using the django-random-id-model
run pip install django-random-id-model
in your django models.py file import RandomIDModel from django-random-id-model
then add RandomIdModel to your model class, in case this is:

class UserOrder(RandomIdModel):
#remaining codes here